# Re-positioning div/ moving div to left and right with JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I am new to javascript and I am trying to start a very simple project which is to display a controllable div that can be moved around using a,w,s,d keys on keyboard. I am currently having problem on how to move around the div because I do not know what attribute to change.

```
divBar = null;

function detectKey() {
    //97 = a
    //115 = s
    //100 = d
    //119 = w

    if (event.charCode == 97) {
       //a
       alert(divBar.position);
    }
    if (event.charCode == 115) {
        //s
    }
    if (event.charCode == 100) {
        //d
    }
    if (event.charCode == 119) {
        //w
    }
}

function createDiv() {
    divBar = document.createElement("div");
    divBar.id = "divBar";
    divBar.style.border = "solid 1px #AAAAAA";
    divBar.style.backgroundColor = "black";
    divBar.style.top = 400;
    divBar.style.height = "10px";
    divBar.style.width = "100px";
    divBar.style.position = "absolute";
    document.body.appendChild(divBar);
    document.addEventListener("keypress", detectKey, false);

}
```

I am not sure to put in that condition statement. so that the div will move to the left, right, up and down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's absolutely positioned (which it appears to be), then you change divbar.style.top and divbar.style.left to move it around.

Here's a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/rRbZz/.

Comment: Works here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/rRbZz/.  Your code contained some errors.  You can see my fixed code in the jsfiddle.

Answer (score 1):

Since it's absolutely positioned, you are most likely going to want to change it's top/left style attributes.  It will involve reading the current top/left attributes, and then adding/subtracting from them after a a,w,s,d key is pressed, and then adding that value back.  So for each key/direction, you are going to have to figure out what impact that will have on the element.  will it move it up/down (affect the top attribute) or left/right (affect the left attribute).  Read what's there, make the appropriate calculations, and the update the attribute.  The trickiest part IMO is reading the initial style.top/style.left attributes, but since you are setting them with Javascript, then you shouldn't have a problem.